# Text to speech(TTS)-Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am new to the android platform. Now I am working on `TTS(Text to Speech)`.If I enter the text in a TextArea and I would like it to be converted to speech when i click the speak button.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Text to speech is built into Android 1.6+. Here is a simple example of how to do it.

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

More info: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

---

[Here are instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) on how to download sample code from the Android SDK Manager:

1. Launch the Android SDK Manager.

   a. On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK directory.

   b. On Mac or Linux, open a terminal to the tools/ directory in the Android SDK, then execute android sdk.
2. Expand the list of packages for the latest Android platform.
3. Select and download Samples for SDK.
   When the download is complete, you can find the source code for all samples at this location:

**/sdk/samples/android-version/**

```
(i.e. \android-sdk-windows\samples\android-16\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app\TextToSpeechActivity.java)
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out the best approach for each platform version. The Samples for SDK.

Comment: i get a `speak` is deprecated at the moment

Comment: it's because the one that is not deprecated is: `speak(CharSequence text,                 int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)`

Comment: You have to wait for TTS to initialize.

Comment: What about Spanish and Turkish, and other languages to import in?

Answer (score 84):

**MainActivity.class**

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String text;
    EditText et;
    TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tts=new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                            result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                        Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                    }
                    else{
                        ConvertTextToSpeech();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(tts != null){

            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        ConvertTextToSpeech();

    }

    private void ConvertTextToSpeech() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        text = et.getText().toString();
        if(text==null||"".equals(text))
        {
            text = "Content not available";
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }else
            tts.speak(text+"is saved", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is a more complete example. It includes the implementation of TextToSpeech.OnInitListener that is missing from the accepted answer. Great stuff! +1

Comment: Thanks for this good stuff!! +1.. But what about if I use this with 1000+ words(Sounds like PDF), Can I implement "Play" and "Pause" with "Resume" option.

Comment: tts.shutdown() should be moved into onDestroy() method.

Answer (score 10):

A minimalistic example to quickly test the TTS system:

```
private TextToSpeech textToSpeechSystem;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  textToSpeechSystem = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                String textToSay = "Hello world, this is a test message!";
                textToSpeechSystem.speak(textToSay, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }
        }
   });
}
```

If you don't use localized messages `textToSpeechSystem.setLanguage(..)` is important as well, since your users probably don't all have English set as their default language so the pronunciation of the words will be wrong. But for testing TTS in general this snippet is enough

Related links: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech

Answer (score 4):

Try this, its simple :
**speakout.xml : **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3498db"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtheader"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight=".1"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="3dp"
android:text="Speak Out!!!"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="25sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edtTexttoSpeak"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".5"
android:background="#fff"
android:textColor="#2c3e50"
android:text="Hi there!!!"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="top|left"
android:layout_height="0dp"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnspeakout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight=".1"
android:background="#e74c3c"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:text="SPEAK OUT"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And Your **SpeakOut.java :**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class SpeakOut extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech repeatTTS;
Button btnspeakout;
EditText edtTexttoSpeak;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.speakout);
    btnspeakout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnspeakout);
    edtTexttoSpeak = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTexttoSpeak);
    repeatTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnspeakout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            repeatTTS.speak(edtTexttoSpeak.getText().toString(),
            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    });
}

@Override
    public void onInit(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

SOURCE [Parallelcodes.com's Post](http://www.parallelcodes.com/android-text-speech-application/)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Texttovoice extends ActionBarActivity implements OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_texttovoice);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    // Refer 'Speak' button
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    // Refer 'Text' control
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    // Handle onClick event for button 'Speak'
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Method yet to be defined
            speakOut();
        }

    });

}

private void speakOut() {
    // Get the text typed
    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    // If no text is typed, tts will read out 'You haven't typed text'
    // else it reads out the text you typed
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        tts.speak("You haven't typed text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    } else {
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }

}

public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.texttovoice, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // TTS is successfully initialized
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        // Setting speech language
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        // If your device doesn't support language you set above
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            // Cook simple toast message with message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Language not supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        }
        // Enable the button - It was disabled in main.xml (Go back and
        // Check it)
        else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
        }
        // TTS is not initialized properly
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TTS Initilization Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}
   //-------------------------------XML---------------

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:text="listen your text"
    android:textColor="#0587d9"
    android:textSize="26dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:hint="Enter text to speak" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Speak" 
    android:onClick="speakout"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
// variable declaration
TextToSpeech tts;

// TextToSpeech initialization, must go within the onCreate method
tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
 @Override
 public void onInit(int i) {
  if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
   int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
   if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
    result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
    Log.e("TTS", "Lenguage not supported");
   }
  } else {
   Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
  }
 }
});

// method call
public void buttonSpeak().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  speak();
 }
});
}

private void speak() {
 tts.speak("Text to Speech Test", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 if (tts != null) {
  tts.stop();
  tts.shutdown();
 }
 super.onDestroy();
}
```

taken from: [Text to Speech Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoYnz0GYN1w)

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.example.text_to_speech;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.fyp.R;

import java.util.Locale;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;

public class textTospeech_class extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    String text;
    int result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_tospeech);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(textTospeech_class.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(textTospeech_class.this, "Not Support in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void tts(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.speechid:
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(textTospeech_class.this, "Not Support in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    textToSpeech.speak("a for apple", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bid:
            {
                if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result== TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(textTospeech_class.this, "Not Support in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    textToSpeech.speak("b for ball",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                }
                break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzBKpZ4nzNzUR05nVUI1aVF6N1k

```
package com.keshav.speechtotextexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private TextView txtSpeechInput;
   private ImageButton btnSpeak;
   private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
      btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

      // hide the action bar
      getActionBar().hide();

      btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
         }
      });

   }

   /**
    * Showing google speech input dialog
    * */
   private void promptSpeechInput() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
      intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
      intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
      intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
      try {
         startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Receiving speech input
    * */
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (requestCode) {
      case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                  .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
         }
         break;
      }

      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}


====================================================

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpeechInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_mic" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/tap_on_mic"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
===============================================================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Speech To Text</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="speech_prompt">Say something&#8230;</string>
    <string name="speech_not_supported">Sorry! Your device doesn\'t support speech input</string>
    <string name="tap_on_mic">Tap on mic to speak</string>

</resources>
===============================================================
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```