# "Cannot find symbol symbol" Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the texttospeech library, however I get error "

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor TextToSpeech(com.example.android.animationsdemo.MainActivity,com.example.android.animationsdemo.MainActivity)
```

It's not the first time I've gotten this error, but I don't understand what it means. What do this error message mean? And how can I fix these errors?

This is my code up to the line with the error:

```
package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {\
    private TextToSpeech talker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        talker = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

Comment: Try this talker = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);

Comment: show your TextToSpeech code I think its constructor is not accepting your context.

Comment: @PadmaKumar He is Using **TextToSpeech** library

Comment: TextToSpeech(Context context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener)
The constructor for the TextToSpeech class, using the default TTS engine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21354040/1012284

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html), the constructor accepts `Context` and `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`. However, your activity doesn't implement `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`.

You have 3 alternatives: make your activity implement the listener, create a named listener, or create an anonymous listener. However, based on your current code, I'll recommend the first approach.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
  implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    ....

    @Override
    public void onInit (int status){
        // implement the listener here
    }
}
```