# Text to speech android code

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I would like to ask about the correction of my problem. I saw an article that teaches how to use text to speech android code but I followed the code and my AVD does not seems to respond. So I went for another code and type it in, the avd does not seems to respond too. Can someone help me to check the error?

```
package net.learn2develop.tts;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnInitListener{

private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE=0;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private EditText inputText;
private Button speakButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    inputText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tts=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
    new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status){
            if(status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);}
            }
        });
    }

@Override
public void onPause(){
    if(tts!=null){
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void speakText(View view){
    String toSpeak=inputText.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tts.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="net.learn2develop.tts.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
    android:onClick="speakText"
    android:text="@string/text1"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
    android:ems="10">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/write"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

Comment: have you tested your code on device?

Comment: I am currently using the same code, testing it on Nexus 5, can't hear any speech from my device. PS: I am using TTS for the first time, and trying to understand it.

Comment: Check out this link: This was working.. http://javatechig.com/android/android-texttospeech-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058919/text-to-speechtts-android/47074960#47074960 **Its Wokring**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058919/text-to-speechtts-android/47074960#47074960 **Its Working**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake is that you haven't initialised your button in the `onCreate`,nor have you given an OnClickListener to it. Another problem here is with your `onInit`. When you're overriding it,try working around like this:

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                button1.setEnabled(true);
                speakText();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }
```

and the entire code would look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button speakButton;
    private EditText inputText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        // button on click event
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                speakButton.setEnabled(true);
                speakText();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakText() {

        String toSpeak = inputText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes that I found :-

1. you do not need to implement onInitListener and override method onInit() because you are using it once and already overriding in OnCreate() method.
2. after onInit() in OnCreate() u need to call speakText() method.

speakText(inputText)