# OSM Maps on native android application using OSMDroid. Now How to implement turn-by-turn voice guidance?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Mostly from past one week I was searching for a tutorials/some reference docs or steps/ sample code to include Open street map into android native application.

**Scenario:** I am able to show the map inside the app using sample code as below:

```
package osmdemo.demo;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class OsmdroidDemoMap extends Activity {
    private MapView         mMapView;
    private MapController   mMapController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.osm_main);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
        mMapController.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(51500000, -150000);
        mMapController.setCenter(gPt);
    }
}
```

Had a look into the OSMand source code, but there is a problem to reuse their code, as there are 3rd party libs used in it and the code reuse policy in their [FAQs](http://osmand.net/help/faq.html#can_i_code) and the code base is too huge to understand ;)

**Question:** Can anyone put some light with steps/ref. docs/sample code on how to integrate the turn-by-turn voice guidance with the OSMDroid maps?

I would greatly appreciate any inputs. 
*Correct me if there is any mistake, new to android app development :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at osmbonus pack, there's a bunch of routing utilities in there

Tutorials: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki

Examples:

https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/tree/master/OSMNavigator

https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/tree/master/OSMBonusPack

Text To Voice is included with Android. There's no magic there and there's a reasonable example here: [Text to speech(TTS)-Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058919/text-to-speechtts-android)