# How to create Android text to speech application that says "hello world" without using text field to write the text?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am making a simple application where when the user clicks on the button, background voice says "hello world".  I have gone through tutorials but their problem is they all use text field to write the text by the user and then it is executed by the button. But what I want is the user to simply click on the button and voice should say "hello world".

Comment: What do you mean "embedded"?

Comment: Solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058919/text-to-speechtts-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your mainactivity**:-

```
package com.example.tts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   TextToSpeech t1;
   Button b1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
               t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
         }
      });

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak = "hello world";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
         }
      });
   }

   public void onPause(){
      if(t1 !=null){
         t1.stop();
         t1.shutdown();
      }
      super.onPause();
   }
}
```

Comment: What about the xml layout?

Comment: Shobhit ,is there way to execute text to speech using lesser code ?

Comment: @Subijoy i don't think so there can be any lesser code than this...this is the best way to optimize your texttospeech..!and for the xml part.....that's vey simple......only a button is needed