# Android Talkback accessibility events

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, talkback

Is there a way to programatically set to read all views on talkback when certain action is fired (ex. button click) like it is when you tap with 3 fingers at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 - if you just want to read some text: Use speech to text

please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059271/9640177)

Text to speech is built into Android 1.6+. Here is a simple example of how to do it.

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak("Text to say aloud", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

More info: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

**Option 2** - If you are particulate about using talkback

refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59663376/9640177)

```
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES, "pkgname/classname");
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED, "1");
```

Where the pkgname is your package name and the classname is the class name of your accessibility service.

If you need to enable several services or you don't want to destory the previous settings you might want to use : to seperate other services.

Also you might need to run as a system application and you might need the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

this might not work on some versions of Android.

Also refer other answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10061154/9640177)

PS. If it doesn't work, maybe you could find some luck in /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db/secure, that's where Android stores secure settings.