# Downloading Android TTS audio

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

So, I created my first android app which takes input and convert it to audio on a button click. Its working fine.
similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059271/13991602) here.

but, I'm curious to know that is there any way to download the audio file which was converted from text to external storage ?

Comment: You can use the synthesizetofile method.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: thanks, This is what i was searching for.