say something using TTS with adb
I want to use my Android 4.1.2 phone to say something with adb...
Microsoft copilot told me this:
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.intent.action.TTS_SPEAK --es "text" "Hello World" --es "language" "en"

but I don't ear anything...
I tried with my Android 14 phone, and it doesn't work either. I have full sound, so the problem come from the command...
How can I make my phone say something only with adb command?

If you don't make it work you could try a workaround: implement a small app that allows you to be called via intent and that translates the received data to a TTS command as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059271/150978 Alternatively you could try Termux and the command termux-tts-speak.

Yeah, but how can I create my own class in manifest that can take the option of language and text to launch it with adb?

You can add any parameter you want to an intent. In the app you can then receive the parameter and pass it to the TTS call. intent.getStringExtra("language");
